# Initializing an array of structure objects, where those objects were previously stored in struct variables

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, initialization

I defined a structure like so:

```
struct Profile { 
char name[15]; // Name of profile for displaying to screen later
int numberOfPulses;  // Number of pulses that will occur for one Profile run
int lengthOfPulse;  // Length (uSec) of each pulse produced
int timeBetweenPulses;  // Time (uSec) between consecutive pulse outputs
}
```

Then, I create a number of objects of this structure type, storing each in an appropriate variable.

```
struct Profile defaultP = {"Default", 1, 100, 0}; 
struct Profile repeat3 = {"Repeat_3", 3, 100, 2000};
struct Profile shortPulse = {"Short_50us", 1, 50, 0};
struct Profile shortPulseRepeat3 = {"Sh_50_R3", 3, 50, 2000};
struct Profile longPulse = {"Single_300", 1, 300, 0};
struct Profile longPulseRepeat3 = {"Sin_300_R3", 3, 300, 2000};
struct Profile custom = {"Custom", 1, 100, 0};
```

Last, I attempt to assign these variables to an array, and this is where I get many errors including mismatch of type and/or redefinition, etc.

```
struct Profile profileArray[] = {defaultP, repeat3, shortPulse, shortPulseRepeat3, longPulse, longPulseRepeat3, custom};
```

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong, but I am inexperienced and expect it is some sort of pointer issue.
An important note is that I *must* define my struct Profile variables individually as I did, because they are called later in the program.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post sample(s) of the actual errors.

Comment: Also please show the context for this code (i.e. is it global? inside of a function? some of both?).

Comment: aside from anything else, you need a semicolon at the end of your struct definition. It should be `struct Profile { .... };`

Answer (score 0):

You try to initialize an array with the value of variables. That results in the error that the initializers are not constants. Instead, use:

```
struct Profile *profileArray[] = {&defaultP, &repeat3, &shortPulse, &shortPulseRepeat3, &longPulse, &longPulseRepeat3, &custom};
```

Now it is an array of pointers to `Profile` structures.

Note that operating on their values will now change the values in the original structs, for example:

```
profileArray[0]->numberOfPulses++;
```

changes the value of `defaultP.numberOfPulses`

Comment: This was the answer I needed. Thank you Paul.